# How to get user from REST API using cookie-based auth

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Quick context: I'm evaluating possible solutions for authentication for some custom restful endpoints for our WIP headless WordPress site.

**What I'm trying to achieve** is making `is_user_logged_in` return true in my custom endpoint using cookie based auth.

---

Here's my current setup and here's what I've tried.

I have the following in `functions.php`

```php
// create an endpoint for getting a nonce
function get_nonce() {
    return new WP_REST_Response(array('nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )));
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('my-site', 'nonce', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\get_nonce'
    ));
} );
```

```php
function get_orders() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'not_authorized', 'You are not logged in', array('status' => 401) );
    }

    $orders = // ...

    return new WP_REST_Response($orders);
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'my-site', 'orders', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\get_orders',
    ));
} );
```

So in summary this creates two endpoints:

- `/wp-json/my-site/nonce` to generate a nonce
- `/wp-json/my-site/orders` to pull some user data

What I do is:

1. call `GET /wp-json/my-site/nonce` to grab the nonce
2. call `GET /wp-json/my-site/orders?_wpnonce=thepreviousnonce`

What I get back is this error:

```
{
  "code": "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
  "message": "Cookie nonce is invalid",
  "data": {
    "status": 403
  }
}
```

I'm just using the browser and URLs to make the requests and I've checked that the cookies are being included with each request.

**What am I missing? Why am I getting the 403?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nonce you're generating is invalid. making nonce in rest context doesnt work because that also needs a nonce! what it returns is a logged out user nonce.  if you need a token based authentication i recomend [JWT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) 
[wp rest auth documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)